# vbscript get logon username of networkdrives

Tags: vbscript, drive

I'd like to get connected username of each Network Drives. I found it's easy to print out local computer name rather than logon username for network drives connections. Does anyone have idea of this? Thanks.

```
Set wn1 = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.network")
MsgBox(wn1.UserName)
```

Comment: Sorry Tiggaroo but your question is unclear. You say you print the computername and in your code you use the username. Do you mean you want a list of users who are connected to a share ?

Comment: Sorry what I mean is to print out remote logon Username who access the network drive but not local server computer name or logon name

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to enumerate the sessions on the server side if you want to know the login name for shares connected with explicit credentials. The client doesn't store this information. For all other network drives the login name is the name of the current user (`CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName`).